# Multiple security configs for one project

Tags: php, symfony4, php-7.3, symfony-4.3

How is possible to load a specific security config regarding Env variable.

```
security:
        providers:
            #### if getenv(PROJECT) === EXTERNAL
            users:
                entity:
                    class: App\Entity\UserRegister
            #### endOnly For external
            #### if getenv(PROJECT) === INTERNAL
            my_ldap:
                ldap:
                    ...
            #### endOnly for internal
```

My Goal is to use the LDAP for internal project and Database Provider for the external one

Comment: Can't you use `APP_ENV` instead of `PROJECT`? Then you can simply put the configs in the correct directories without any additional coding, see https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-environments

Comment: Maybe with something like this : https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/configuration/environments.html. I will check Thank you EDIT : it's not for 4.3 release ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best solution for symfony is to use different [environments](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-environments).

There are already `dev`, `prod` and `test` environment in your project, so just [add new](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#creating-a-new-environment) `internal` one.

If there is only one setting to change you can [import](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#importing-configuration-files) others:

```
imports:
    - { resource: '../dev/' }
```